# Самый безопасный способ аутентификации

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой способ аутентификации для php сайта сейчас является наиболее безопасным? С использованием сессий и хранением зашифрованных паролей в БД?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А какие ещё существуют способы авторизации? Могу и ошибаться, но тут либо сессии, либо куки.
Что из них лучше - [гугл в помощь](http://prootime.ru/php-sessions-cookies) 
Я для себя выбрал сессии(вся информация хранится на сервере, фиг кто что украдёт).
Ну а пароли конечно лучше хранить в зашифрованном виде, причём без возможности обратной дешифровки - md5($password."Соль"). Для реализации восстановления доступа к аккаунту - старый пароль никак не узнать, просто вводим новый.
Кстати, когда копался в этом вопросе, выяснил, что все сайты, которые высылают вам на e-mail ваш старый пароль, хранят его в незашифрованном виде, так что если их вдруг взломают, злоумышленники увидят ваш пароль как на блюдечке.